# Display Multiple data from database to textview android

Tags: android

my problem is cant display all the data i call from my database to my textview when i click the button , but i can only display 1 data at the time , and i read the other question like this but still i dont get it.

This is my Code to call the data from database

```
 public WordObject getPOSbyWords(String wordd){
    WordObject wordObject2 = null;
    String query2 = "SELECT pos FROM wordbank WHERE words in ("+wordd+")";
    Cursor cursor = this.getDbConnection1().rawQuery(query2,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            //=
            String pos1=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("pos"));
            //String pos2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("words"));
            wordObject2 = new WordObject(pos1,null);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    cursor.close();
    return wordObject2;
}
```

**This my Code in main activity**

```
public class GrammarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView postv, wordtv;
Button btngo;
MultiAutoCompleteTextView multiple;
Listview listview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grammar);
    wordtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grammar);
    multiple = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.MultipleAuto);
    btngo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check);
    postv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Partofspeech);
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);


    //Welcome user
    builder.setMessage("Welcome to the Grammar Checker")
            .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setPositiveButton("Enter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
    builder.create();
    builder.show();


    //Space Tokenizer splitting the words

    final String[] words = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.autocomplete);
    multiple.setTokenizer(new SpaceTokenizer());
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, words);
    multiple.setAdapter(adapter);

    btngo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            String space = "";
            String foo = " ";
            String foo1 = ",";
            String sentences = null;
            String red = multiple.getText().toString();

            if (red.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Input text please ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                multiple.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "THanks ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //Splitting the sentence into words
            sentences = multiple.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
            String[] splitwords = sentences.trim().split("\\s+");

            for (String biyak : splitwords) {
                foo = (foo + "'" + biyak + "'" + foo1);
                String fot = foo.replaceAll(",$", " ");
                wordtv.setText(fot);

                Db1Backend db1Backend = new Db1Backend(GrammarActivity.this);
                WordObject DisplayPOS = db1Backend.getPOSbyWords(fot);


                postv.setText(DisplayPOS.getWord());

            }
```

World Class

```
public class WordObject {
private String word;
private String pos;

public WordObject(String word, String definition) {
    this.word = word;
    this.pos = definition;
}

public String getWord() {
    return word;
}

public void setWord(String word) {
    this.word = word;
}    

public String getPOS() {
    return pos;
}

public void setPOS(String definition) {
    this.pos = definition;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are creating every time new object for this  wordObject2 = new WordObject(pos1,null); that's why you see only one record. Better to append all the records in one string and call the method once. Can you please post the WordObject class.

Comment: see my answer sir :)

Comment: Yo. bro! it works thanks alot

Comment: can i ask how your code works?

Comment: Ya sure sir. For query I am only taking the string not the WordObject bean because you only require the Position so need to use whole bean.Now move to activity part.I take StringBuilder which append all your data into one sb object so whenever your for loop start looping it goes to fetch the query in database then the result store in sb now again this cycle do upto your size. Now once the for loop done I set the sb to your textview so it will show all your position in your textview.

Comment: Woah,  nice idea. can i one thing again, can i modify the output of the for loop before i put it in the textview?

Comment: yes you can modify the out put no worries sir :)

Comment: sir , there's a problem in the output of your code , i thought at first it's in query but when i try my query to SQLite , i got my expected answer, but there's something wrong in the code. 

example: expected output is : 
"panghalip"
"pandiwa"
"panghalip"
"pang-ukol"
"pandiwa"
the output of the code is :
"panghalip"
"pandiwa"
"panghalip"
"pandiwa"
"pandiwa"

Comment: I wasn't change any query it is the same query as you posted in your question. It is good you used your query and its working :) . The output you got wrong is the reason of your for loop your for loop looping upto your splitwords size but your query has more that spliwords size that's why it is not giving you exact result.

Comment: as i thought , there's a problem with my for loop , What do you mean of my query has more splitwords than my for loop? what im going to do right now?

Comment: But thanks you have time to reply again :)

Comment: I mean to say that for E.g Your for loop is start looping upto 5 records but may be it is possible that your have less number of records in DB or more number of records in DB. Please find it out using log printing what you get in out put so you get exactly idea what is going on.

Comment: Logcat(error) says : spannablestringbuilder : span_exclusive_exclusive span cannot have a zero lenght

Comment: but in when i view logcat , the logcat (verbose) it open the database 5 times

Comment: can you help me to debug this , im just new to this kind of problem

Comment: System.out.println("===== VALUE GET ====::"+db1Backend.getPOSbyWords(fot)+":::"); add this line before sb.append() and this line System.out.println("===== SB VALUES ===::"+sb.toString()+"::"); after sb.append() and see what values you get and you will get some idea what is going wrong.

Comment: now , i know! there's a problem in SQLITE , i try to change my database for testing , i get what i want to seee. (my orignal database Has a almost 4k rows) and the proxy database has 10 rows only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
public String getPOSbyWords(String wordd)
{
   String myPos = "";
   String query2 = "SELECT pos FROM wordbank WHERE words in ("+wordd+")";
   Cursor cursor = this.getDbConnection1().rawQuery(query2,null);

   try
   {
     if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0)
     {
       while (cursor.moveToNext())
       {
         String pos1=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("pos"));
         myPos = pos1;
       }
     }
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
     // Handle Exception here
   }
   finally
   { 
      // release cursor
      if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed())
          cursor.close();
   }
  return myPos;
}
```

Now in your GrammarActivity inside for loop do this.

```
// Taking String Builder to append all the String in one.
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String biyak : splitwords)
{
    foo = (foo + "'" + biyak + "'" + foo1);
    String fot = foo.replaceAll(",$", " ");
    wordtv.setText(fot);

    Db1Backend db1Backend = new Db1Backend(GrammarActivity.this);
    // Append all your position into StringBuilder
    sb.append(db1Backend.getPOSbyWords(fot));
}
postv.setText(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your method with this.

```
public ArrayList<WordObject> getPOSbyWords(String wordd){
    WordObject wordObject2 = null;
    String query2 = "SELECT pos FROM wordbank WHERE words in ("+wordd+")";
    Cursor cursor = this.getDbConnection1().rawQuery(query2,null);
    ArrayList<WordObject> words = new ArrayList<>();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            //=
            String pos1=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("pos"));
            //String pos2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("words"));
            wordObject2 = new WordObject(pos1,null);
            words.add(wordObject2);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    cursor.close();
    return words;
}
```

Comment: How im going to implement that code to my mainactivity? i should change it too? `Db1Backend db1Backend = new Db1Backend(GrammarActivity.this);
                WordObject DisplayPOS = db1Backend.getPOSbyWords(fot);


                postv.setText(DisplayPOS.getWord());
`

Comment: i try to change it but i end with error
`Db1Backend db1Backend = new Db1Backend(GrammarActivity.this);
                    ArrayList<WordObject> DisplayPOS = db1Backend.getPOSbyWords(fot);
                    postv.setText(DisplayPOS);`